# FQL query for non empty array OR how to query messages with attachments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to find all messages with FQL that have some attachments.

I would like to optimilize my FQL to search only for messages that actually have some attachements insted of going thru each of them on the server.

According to [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_message) there is an attachments field but I am not sure how to query by it.

I was thinking something like

> SELECT body, attachments FROM unified_message WHERE thread_id = 't_mid.tID' and attachments != []

or maybe you can suggest other way how to find messages with attachments

Thank you!

Comment: Usually FQL treats any non-empty value as true and empty values as false, so just try with `… AND attachments`

Comment: nope, that is not helping :( I get 0 results :(

Answer (score 0):

I can produce a valid result using the following FQL (on my own inbox):

```
SELECT body, attachments  FROM unified_message where thread_id in (select thread_id from unified_thread  where folder = 'inbox') and attachments
```

I guess you have a problem in the

```
...WHERE thread_id = 't_mid.tID'...
```

part. You can only use subselects and IN statements with FQL. Or do you fill the 't_mid.tID' via your apllication language as a variable?